# Execute command after dpkg installation?

Tags: installation, dpkg

I just got inspired of this project:

> http://www.opendesktop.org/content/show.php?content=145633

Well , i wanted to do a similar thing , after dpkg places something new in /usr/share/applications directory , but where should my script point to , and the parameter to pass in ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the script do not takes parameters, add a file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`, for example `92local` (numbers are used to force execution order of scripts in that directory), with the following content:

```
DPkg::Post-Invoke { "/path-to/my-script"; };
```

and remember to make it executable.

Cannot find right now information on how to pass parameter or input to the script.
If can be of help, when running `apt` on command line, you should find the command line in the environment variable `SUDO_COMMAND`.

Comment: i modified that script to find all the .desktop files automatically , so far my problem is resolved , thanks !

Answer (score 3):

I have found a way to get the commandline of the APT command executed:

Create a file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90my_dpkg_post_invoke` with content

```
DPkg::Post-Invoke { "/usr/local/lib/my_dpkg_post_invoke.sh"; }
```

Create an executable file `/usr/local/lib/my_dpkg_post_invoke.sh` with content

```
#!/bin/bash
APTPID=$( ps -ho ppid "${PPID}" )
APTPID="${APTPID## }"   # trim leading spaces
APTCMD=$( ps -ho args "${APTPID}" )
APTCMD="${APTCMD## }"   # trim leading spaces
echo "#### APT Command: ${APTCMD}"
```

Now you can extend the executable file with a test if the `${APTCMD}` contains a string you want to trigger an action for.